# While loop to check email exist in DB PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

My code is not working i want to check Email exist in db or show message email exit or not when click tab button:

HTML:

````
<input class="form-control" type="text"  name="email" id="email" onkeyup="checkemail();" required>```
````

PHP:

```
<?php
    $checkemail = mysqli_query($conn, "Select email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'")
    while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkemail) > 0)
         {
          echo "Email Already Exist :)";
         }
         else
         {
          echo "OK  :)";
         }
        exit();
        }
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` doesn't return an integer. You should first prevent SQL injections, `Select count(*) FROM users WHERE email = ?` (and just get a count). Then execute, check the return and output based on that.

Comment: Use `mysqli_num_rows($checkemail) ` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkemail)`. Try This

Comment: You need to check if it's `NULL`. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `num_row` like that:

```
 $checkemail = $conn->prepare("Select email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
 $checkemail->bind_param('s',$email);
 $checkmail->execute();
 $result = $checkmail->get_result();
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   echo 'mail exist'; exit();
  }else{
  echo "mail doesn't exist";
  }
```

i change part of the code for improve security

Comment: What is the point in selecting the values if you do not use them?

Comment: @Dharman for check if email exist or not you must select it no?

Answer (score -1):

Use `mysqli_num_rows($checkemail)` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkemail)`

Because `mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkemail)` does not return a integer. It returns an associative array.

```
$checkemail = mysqli_query($conn, "Select email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'")
        
         if(mysqli_num_rows($checkemail) > 0)
             {
              echo "Email Already Exist :)";
             }
             else
             {
              echo "OK  :)";
             }
            exit();
            }
        
        
        ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) ....There some error in here??

Comment: Corrected. Now it should work